# Full graph without calculating all points, possible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphics, tabs

I would like to draw a graph with predefined values from 0 to 605 for example. My pc is not powerful enough to calculate everything so I would like to calculate only some points and connect them all to have a curve on the interval [0;605]. How can I do this? Is this possible?
I tried to put a step, but it automatically reduces the interval.

In my current code it only shows me 605/10 values = 60, so the range of the graph is from 0 to 60 for the x-axis.

```
tab=[]

for k in range(1,605,10): 

    img2 = rgb(k)

    d = psnr(img1,img2)

    tab.append(d)

plt.plot(tab)
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.ylabel("PSNR")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, please post enough code for people to be able to run your example. This shows functions `rgb()` and `psnr()` being called, but not their definitions.

Comment: @baileythegreen yes but it's a math formula that returns a float every time

Comment: That doesn't matter. We can't tell that, and we still can't run the code to try debugging without it. You should always try to post minimum reproducible examples here, so that people can try to reproduce the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the xticks by yourself: `plt.xticks(x_values, [0, 10, 20, 30, ...])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to plot with the pattern `plt.plot(x, y)` instead of only `plt.plot(y)`.

A quick fix (just to show the idea) can be:

1. Create an empty x, just like tab: `x = []`
2. Append k to x in the loop: `x.append(k)`
3. Do `plt.plot(x, tab)`, instead of `plt.plot(tab)`